# How to add OPTION RECOMPILE into Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am experiencing [parameter sniffing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/) problem sometimes.
So I would like to add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of query to fix it.
How can I do it in EF 6?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I implemented IDbCommandInterceptor interface to fix the parameter sniffing error.

The usage of the new interceptor:

```
  using (var dataContext = new AdventureWorks2012Entities())
  {
    var optionRecompileInterceptor = new OptionRecompileInterceptor();
    DbInterception.Add(optionRecompileInterceptor);

    string city = "Seattle";
    var seattle = (
      from a in dataContext.Addresses
      where a.City == city
      select a).ToList();

    DbInterception.Remove(optionRecompileInterceptor); //Remove interceptor to not affect other queries
  }
```

Implementation of the interceptor:

```
public class OptionRecompileInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
  static void AddOptionToCommand(DbCommand command)
  {
    string optionRecompileString = "\r\nOPTION (RECOMPILE)";
    if (!command.CommandText.Contains(optionRecompileString)) //Check the option is not added already
    {
      command.CommandText += optionRecompileString;
    }
  }


  public override void NonQueryExecuting(
    DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
  {
    AddOptionToCommand(command);
  }

  public override void ReaderExecuting(
    DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
  {
    AddOptionToCommand(command);
  }

  public override void ScalarExecuting(
    DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
  {
    AddOptionToCommand(command);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good, but it would be easier if you inherit `DbCommandInterceptor` class, so you don't have to override the unneeded methods.

Comment: I would use `try ... finally` to ensure that `DbInterception.Remove` always gets called.

Comment: @Rudey or let it implement `IDisposable` so it can be used in a `using` statement

Comment: I used this as a base for a .NET Core 3.1 app with the same issue. I'll post that with some updates, since core kind of sucks when you have to hunt down the packages and namespaces if they aren't specified. Times went from ~35s to 350ms! (3.1 was the first Core version to have interceptors exposed, apparently)

Answer (score 4):

If you are here and you are using EF Core, you can add an interceptor and tag them in the query. Super easy, but sometimes hard to find references.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Answer (score 2):

In EF core 6 there is no static **DbInterception.Remove** method and that will cause **all** the queries to be processed get that with recompile option.

You can read the following article from Microsoft describing how it is done for adding **OPTION (ROBUST PLAN)** to your TSQLs by adding a simple tag to your code and it works the same for adding **OPTION (RECOMPILE)**

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs.TagWith("Use hint: RECOMPILE").ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints

--update

check below page for more explanation
https://davecallan.com/how-to-add-sql-query-hints-to-entity-framework-core-queries/