# EF Core order by on a left joined property is very slow (but SQL generated is fast)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, left-join, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have 2 tables (Assets and Categories) and I want to order my result with a left join property.

I wrote this code:

```
dBcontext.Assets
.OrderBy(x => x.Category.Name)
.Then(x => x.Name)
.Skip(0).Take(100)
.AsNoTracking()
.Select(x => x.Name)
.ToList();
```

EF Core generate this query:

```
SELECT [f].Name
FROM Asset AS [f]
LEFT JOIN [Category] AS [c] ON [f].[CategoryId] = [c].[Id]
ORDER BY [c].[Name], [f].[Name]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Now, my problem is that, when I run the application, in the debug console, this query takes more than 4s (*Executed DbCommand (4,968ms)*).
But the same query directly executed in SSMS, takes 300ms.

I don't know why and I need help.

FYI : I have +3M items in table Assets, 20k in table Category and I have set an Index on Asset.Name and Category.Name

Debug console log: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlEL8.png)
SQL execution log: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX1eq.png)

### UPDATE 1

In response to @SvyatoslavDanyliv

I executed my code in LINQPad and it takes 3s (like my application).

Apparently EFCore generate this query :

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
DECLARE @p1 Int = 100
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t3].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT [t2].[Name], [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t1].[Path], [t0].[Name]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[Name]
        FROM [FunctionalAssets2] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Structure] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[StructureId]
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
    ) AS [t3]
ORDER BY [t3].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

I executed this query in SMSS and it takes also 3s.

It seems that the SQL query in debug console is not the real query which is executed.

The execution time issue seems to come from the ROW_NUMBER in the query

### UPDATE 2

I profiled my SQL query with XEvent Profiler and entity framework generate a good query (with OFFSET/FETCH). It's linqpad which does crap.

Finally, I found that is parameter sniffing which affects the performance.
So, I create an interceptor and I added OPTION (recompile) at the end of my query ([How to add OPTION RECOMPILE into Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387037/how-to-add-option-recompile-into-entity-framework)).

But I'm still not satisfied with the performance, so I think that in the future I will try to use a search engine (SOLR).

Comment: problem is not sql or the query , you have to find the root cause inside your app

Comment: There is a great article: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings). But how to apply it to EF... You need to study and change the settings.

Comment: A I know EF generates parameters for OFFSET and FETCH. Maybe bad execution plan is used?

Comment: @eshirvana it's not the application (I edited my post). I see the executed dbcommand time in debug console.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv How can I see the entity framework generated execution plan ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I tried with different settings. I don't have significant difference.

Comment: The SSMS query doesn't use variables for `TenantId`. That may also cause a difference. Also, I assume you also have an index on `CategoryId`? (Although that doesn't affect this issue).

Comment: @GertArnold Itried the query in SSMS with a variable for TenantId, still the same response time.
Yes, I have an index on CategoryId.

Comment: Ok, try to run this query in LINQPad. Add your context and use the same LINQ query.

Comment: Another difference may be caused by using varchar parameters on an nvarchar column, or reverese. EF needs to know if `TenantId` is a unicode field or not.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it seems that row_number is a problem in this query.
Is it possible to force EFCore not to use row_number ?

Comment: Try to move `Select` before `Skip`. It is weird that EF Core generated such SQL.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it generates almost the same query.
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t1].[Path], [t0].[Name]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [FunctionalAssets2] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Structure] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[StructureId]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN p0+ 1 AND p0 + p1
ORDER BY [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]

Comment: Wait, SQL that you have provided has nothing with question's LINQ query,

Comment: That is **shockingly** byzantine SQL! Whiskey? Tango? Foxtrot? Maybe  submit it to https://worsethanfailure.com/ ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Soory , I was in vacation without an internet connection...
I know the SQL in my comment is not the same as the one in my post.

Comment: I wanted  to simplify my scenario. The difference is just in the properties naming

Comment: Try to move `.Select(x => x.Name)` before `Skip`. It can make translation for EF Core more easier.